# How to handle both Firebase DynamicLink and plain DeepLink at the same time?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

I'm confused about google docs, in handling both plain deepLinks and firebase dynamic links at the same time.

To handle plain deepLinks, I had this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    parseDeepLink(data);
}
```

To add support for firebase dynamic links ( and firebase app invites), the docs suggest to use this:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
.getDynamicLink(getIntent())
.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
            Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();

            // Extract invite
            FirebaseAppInvite invite = FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(pendingDynamicLinkData);
            if (invite != null) {
                String invitationId = invite.getInvitationId();

                // handle invite
            }

            parseDeepLink(deepLink);
        }
    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

However, with the above updated code, I can't receive plain deepLinks as pendingDynamicLinkData is always null with plain deepLinks. Should I be using `parseDeepLink(getIntent().getData())` in `onFailure()` method?

What is the correct way to handle both plain DeepLinks and Firebase Dynamic Links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-dynamic links you should just use

`Uri data = intent.getData();`

As you were before. You can check that in your success callback, e.g.

```
if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
        Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();

        // Extract invite
        FirebaseAppInvite invite = FirebaseAppInvite.getInvitation(pendingDynamicLinkData);
        if (invite != null) {
            String invitationId = invite.getInvitationId();

            // handle invite
        }

        parseDeepLink(deepLink);
    } else {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        parseDeepLink(data);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently doing this way i.e. using getIntent().getData() if pendingDyanmicLinkData == null. I initially thought, plain deepLinks would trigger onFailure() method rather than onSuccess() method. I was wondering if this is correct way or if there are better graceful solutions available for the purpose. Any idea when onFailure() method is triggered? I couldn't trigger it in any case.

Comment: On failure is called if it is a dynamic link but doesn't process properly - genuine error case though, shouldn't occur in normal flow